# PowerShell Export-CSV to Multiple Paths

Tags: powershell, export-csv, select-object

I'm trying to export the contents of folders in a directory to a CSV. The issue I'm running into is that I can't figure out how to get the export to 2 different paths.

Simply adding another Export-Csv just adds a empty Csv to the 2nd path.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path *root_path* -Filter *.zip -Recurse | 
Select-Object BaseName, CreationTime |

Export-Csv -Path "*path1*_$((Get-Date).ToString(' yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss')).csv"

Export-Csv -Path *path2*_$((Get-Date).ToString(' yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss')).csv
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's because econd export is not part of the pipeline.
You could store the results first and then export them.

```
$dat = Get-ChildItem -Path *root_path* -Filter *.zip -Recurse | Select-Object BaseName, CreationTime 
'*path1*','*path2*' | foreach {Export-Csv -InputObject $dat -Path "$_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss')).csv"}
```

Comment: So your script does output 2 csv but, its not outputting the details collected by the "Select-Object". I tried storing the "Select-Object" with no luck.

Comment: @duckfeet23 The part with select-object you got right in your question. Anyway I added it, try now.

Comment: It's giving a me a error basically stating the paths can't be in the middle of the pipe.

Comment: @duckfeet23 Because they can't, I made a mistake. Remove extra |, it should be 2 separate pipelines. Also, don't create paths like that, join-path is safer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Tee-Object`.

One-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path *root_path* -Filter *.zip -Recurse | Select-Object BaseName, CreationTime |ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Tee-Object -FilePath "*path1*_$((Get-Date).ToString(' yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss')).csv" -Append | Out-File "*path2*_$((Get-Date).ToString(' yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss')).csv"
```

See Example 3 of the [Tee-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-7#example-3--convert-the-powershell-event-log-to-csv) docu.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is that you want to export the same thing to two different files?

```
$data = Get-ChildItem -Path *root_path* -Filter *.zip -Recurse 
 
$data | Select-Object BaseName, CreationTime | Export-Csv -Path "*path1*_$((Get-Date).ToString(' yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss')).csv"
$data | Select-Object BaseName, CreationTime | Export-Csv -Path "*path2*_$((Get-Date).ToString(' yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss')).csv"
```